# what could cause the htaccess file to be modified?

Tags: htaccess, ftp

One of the wordpress sites that I created recently went down with a *500 internal server error*. After hours of mind boggling and checking error logs, I found out that the `htaccess` files present in the user directory had been modified, with an `ss` added to the end of the file which caused the error. After changing and uploading the file, the site got back up.

I wanted to know what could have caused this? It is hosted on a godaddy server, and the permission for the file is 604. was the server hacked or did wordpress somehow write this into the file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen when the rewrite rules are flushed. The function `insert_with_markers()` is using `fopen()`, but *not* [`flock()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php), so when two pieces of code are calling `flush_rewrite_rules()` almost at the same time, the second process can write to that file before the first one has closed it.

Check your plugins and your theme for `flush_rewrite_rules()`, especially those registering custom post types or taxonomies. Some poorly written plugins are calling this on every page load. Disable that plugin.

Comment: thanks for this. I will go through my plugin files to see where this functions is called.